# Requested module does not provide an export?

Tags: node.js

First post here, be gentle :)

I'm in the process of learning a bit of node.js and I'm trying to do some stuff with a module called 'node-bom'

I am familiar with the 'require' method for calling node modules. However the author has provided the following code example, which doesn't work with node.js:

```
import {Bom} from 'node-bom'

const bom = new Bom({
  /// options
})

bom.getParsedStateData('VIC', {
  bypassCache: false // default: false to use cache
})
  .then((stateData) => {
    console.log(stateData)
    /*
      {
        forecast: {}, // forecast data
        observations: {} // current station's observations data
      }
    */
  })
```

This code produces the following error:

```
(node:10363) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///Users/ajudge/node-bom-testing/index.mjs:1
import {Bom} from 'node-bom'
        ^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'node-bom' does not provide an export named 'Bom'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:93:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:108:20)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:128:24)
```

I've done some further reading and this appears to be an ES6 issue. So, I have changing the file to a .mjs and using the --experimental-modules flag, but I'm still not having any luck.

Can anyone clarify what I need to modify to get this module to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your filename to `.js`

The example in the package docs is more TypeScript oriented (hence the `import`).

In Node.JS your code should look like:

```js
const Bom = require('node-bom')

const bom = new Bom.Bom({
  /// options
})

bom.getParsedStateData('VIC', {
  bypassCache: false // default: false to use cache
})
  .then((stateData) => {
    console.log(stateData)
    /*
      {
        forecast: {}, // forecast data
        observations: {} // current station's observations data
      }
    */
  })
```

Comment: what do you get when you run `node --version` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue entirely. I have a new error message now:

```
const Bom = new bom({
            ^

TypeError: bom is not a constructor
    at file:///Users/ajudge/node-bom-testing/index.mjs:3:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:111:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:128:24)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've tried both syntaxes as you've suggested. I still see:

node --experimental-modules index.mjs 
(node:11756) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///Users/ajudge/node-bom-testing/index.mjs:3
const bom = new Bom.Bom({
            ^

TypeError: Bom.Bom is not a constructor
    at file:///Users/ajudge/node-bom-testing/index.mjs:3:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:111:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:128:24)

Comment: why are creating an .mjs file and not a simple js file?

Comment: Only because from my reading ES6 stuff doesn't work in nodejs unless you use a .mjs file extension, and the --experimental-modules flag. I could be wrong though!

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: try to rename ... :)

Comment: Yeah, I have. It fails. The details on the .mjs stuff are here:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: just tested on my machine - see the fix

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much! I'll go back over the doco for that module, see if I can see how you got it working. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I simply modified the code to node.js standard. If you want to work like the author does - create a Typescript project (`.ts` files)